# Task is logged but not executing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a cron job which runs on my db and creates tasks to process certain db records. The cron job runs as expected, but the tasks added with `taskqueue.add()` don't really function. They are logged in the logs of the app, but nothing happens. I also put some `logging.info()` code in the tasks, but it's not executing. This is really puzzling beacuse I'm not getting any errors, and if I access the task directly (through a URL in the browser) it executes fine.

Here's the log:
[image]

Here's the empty_task.py code:

```
import webapp2
import logging

class EmptyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info("empty task!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/tasks/empty_task', EmptyHandler),
], debug=True)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the `cron.yaml` code:

```
cron:
- description: the shots dispatcher
  url: /tasks/run_schedules
  schedule: every 15 minutes
```

And here's the `run_schedules` code:

```
import webapp2
import logging

from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import Cursor
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

from models.schedule import Schedule

MAX_FETCH = 20

class RunSchedulesHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('cursor'))
        scheds, next_curs, more = Schedule.query().fetch_page(MAX_FETCH, keys_only=True, start_cursor=cursor)

        for key in scheds:
            logging.info("adding to taskqueue schedule: {}".format(key.id()))
            taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/process_schedule', params={'sid': key.id()})
            taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/empty_task', params={'sid': key.id()})

        if more and next_curs:
            taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/run_schedules', params={'cursor': next_curs})

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/tasks/run_schedules', RunSchedulesHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you please show the cron.yaml you're using...?  And as much as needed of the rest of your code+config to allow reproducing...

Comment: @AlexMartelli I've added the `cron.yaml` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default method of task execution is `POST`. And you have only defined the `GET` method in `EmptyHandler`. See the appengine console status. Its returning `405` which is `method not allowed`.

You can use 2 solution for this.

**Solution 1:**
Change the method name to post.

```
class EmptyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info("empty task!")
```

**Solution 2:** Define method explicitly in `taskqueue.add()`

```
taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/empty_task', params={'sid': key.id()}, method='GET')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I feel retarded and exalted at the same :) Thanks